# Eliminar registro con laravel y ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

**El Error que me tira **
***Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message***

**Los datos si me los identifica pero creo que el error esta en el ajax **

**ESTE ES MI FORMULARIO**

```
{{Form::open(array( 'url'=>'#','id'=>'formulario','method'=>'post'))}}


                    <h1>Eliminar<span class="badge badge-secondary">Productos</span></h1>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('id', 'Id:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            {!! Form::text('id',$product->id, ['readonly'=>'true'], $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('producto', 'Producto:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            {!! Form::text('producto',$product->producto, ['readonly'=>'true'],  $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre del Producto']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('marca', 'Marca:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            {!! Form::text('marca',$product->marca, ['readonly'=>'true'],  $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Marca Del Producto']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('precio', 'Precio:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            {!! Form::text('precio',$product->precio, ['readonly'=>'true'],  $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Precio del Producto']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('cantidad', 'Cantidad:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            {!! Form::text('cantidad',$product->cantidad, ['readonly'=>'true'],  $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Cantidad del Producto']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('descripcion', 'Descripcion:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            {!! Form::textarea('descripcion',$product->comentario, ['readonly'=>'true'],  $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','maxlength'=>'150', 'placeholder' => 'Descripcion del Producto']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <span class="btn btn-danger" onclick="submit()" id="enviar">Enviar</span>
                    </div>

                    {{Form::close()}}
```

**ESTE ES MI AJAX**

```
<script>
function submit() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        header: $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    });

    $('#enviar');
    var url = 'productoeliminar2';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $('#formulario').serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if ((obj.estado == 'ok')) {
                alert(obj.mensaje);
                window.location = "{{ route('producto') }}"
            } else {
                alert(obj.mensaje);
                $('#enviar').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**mi ruta **

```
Route::post('productoeliminar2',[
'as'=>'productoeliminar2',
'uses'=>'inventario@productoeli2'
```

]);

**Y esta es mi funcion que elimina **

```
public static function productoeli2(Request $request){
    \DB::beginTransaction();
    try{
        productos::where('id','=',$request->id)->delete();
        \DB::commit();
        return response()->json(['mensaje'=>'transaccion guardada','estado'=>'ok'],200);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \DB::rollback();
        return response()->json(['mensaje'=>$e->getMessage(),'estado'=>'error'],200);
    }
```

Comment: ahi esta como productoeliminar2 esa es la ruta la cual me tiene que entrar en la funcion productoeli2 ahi la coloque

Comment: ¿cómo así que los datos sí los identifica? ¿en dónde los identifica? ¿la ruta aparece definida en el listado de rutas de artisan?

Comment: No sé cómo estén organizados los templates, pero ¿no sería posible llamar a la ruta por su nombre en JS? algo así: `var url = {{route('productoeliminar2')}}`

Comment: los parametros  si me los envia pero a la hora de obtener una respues me tira este   { error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message*}

Comment: Pregunto de nuevo: ¿aparece la ruta definida con el método POST en el listado de rutas de artisan?

Comment: Si si esta definida la ruta con el metodo POST ahi deje como esta la ruta definida en el documento donde dice mi ruta

Comment: Creo que no me hice entender, bueno, espero que lo pueda resolver, realmente es un problema simple.

Comment: es que soy nuevo utilizando laravel pero gracias

Answer (score 0):

1.- Verificar que tu ruta la esté detectando Laravel:

```
php artisan route:list
```

2.- Si no aparece puede ser por que, probablemente, no esté bien definida, si tu controlador se llama inventario desde ahí viene el error) tu ruta debería quedar algo como esto:

```
Route::post('productoeliminar2','InventarioController@productoeli2') -> name('productoeliminar2'); 
/* Se puede notar que el nombre del controllador cambió */
```

3.- Maneja el error en Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (data) {
        ....
    },
    error: function (data){
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

4.-Las buenas prácticas de Laravel nos indican que los modelos deben comenzar por mayúsculas y manejarse en singular, en tu caso debería ser:

```
Producto::where('id','=',$request->id)->delete();
```

Yo dejaría tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
$prod = Producto::find($request->id);
$prod->delete();
```

Espero puedas resolver tu duda.